# In state navigation not working after removing baseHref Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, routes, ngrx-store

I've changed my base url from  `<base href="/login/">` to  `<base href="/">`, now all my in state navigations are broken and going to error page.

My App as a Forgot Password Link, When user clicks on it should navigate to `login/recover`, but it goes to 404 page.

```
 // console.log state
 // name: "login.recover"
 // path: "login/recover"

if(state) {
  if(state.name !== this.currentFormState.name) {
    console.log(state);
    this.router.navigate([state.path],{ skipLocationChange : false });
    this.setState(stateName);
  } else {
    this.componentRefreshNotifier.next();
  }
}
```

But If I access my url directly in browser `login/recover` it works.

What I'm doing wrong here ? Please guide me

Comment: Your paths need to now be prefixed with `login`. before they didn't have to. did you change them?

Comment: yes, before it was just `/recover` ive changed it to `login/recover`

Comment: You might want to add the slash in front of `login/recover` so it looks like `/login/recover`

Comment: I tried that also, but it doesn't work

Comment: Off-Topic: `{ skipLocationChange : false }` isn't needed since it defaults to a falsy value.

Comment: yes, it turned true, for debugging I turned to false to check the it goes to correct url which it does